# Positive definiteness of matrix in special case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be symmetric and let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $B^T \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$. We consider the matrix
$$K=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B^T\\
B & C
\end{bmatrix}.$$

 I have shown that $K=LDL^T$, where
$$L=\begin{bmatrix}
I_n\\
Q & I_m
\end{bmatrix},D=\begin{bmatrix}
H\\
 & S
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $H=A$, $Q=BA^{-1}$ and $S=C-BA^{-1}B^T$.

 I have also shown that $K$ is positive definite if and only if both $H$ and $S$ are positive definite.

 The question is: in the case when $C=O$, is $K$ positive definite? Is it negative definite? Is it indefinite?

 So if $C=O$, we have $S=-BA^{-1}B^T$ and
$$K=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B^T\\
B & O
\end{bmatrix}.$$

 I think it is indefinite, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That matrix has zeros on the diagonal, therefore it cannot be definite. At best, it might be *semi*-definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $B\ne0$, we have $b_{ij}\ne0$ for some $i$ and $j$. Therefore $K$ contains a principal submatrix $\pmatrix{a_{jj}&b_{ij}\\ b_{ij}&0}$ that is indefinite because the product of its two eigenvalues (i.e. its determinant) is negative. Hence $K$ is indefinite.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $K$ is of size $(m+n)\times (m+n)$ with lower right $m\times m$ part being the zero matrix (C in your notation).

Take $v= e_{n+i}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots m$ (standard basis vectors)

Then simple matrix multiplication yields $Kv=0$. So $v^tKv=0$, violating positive definiteness.

Comment: That only shows that it is not positive definite. However, it can be semi-definite or negative-semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

Seek the help of [Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues). The matrix $K$ is congruent to $D$ and hence they have the same inertia (number of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues). This has two consequences:

1. $K$ is positive definite if and only if $D$ is which is positive definite if and only if $H$ and $S$ are.
2. If $C$ is zero, $S$ is negative definite and hence $K$ is indefinite. In addition, $K$ has $n$ positive and $m$ negative eigenvalues.